# Connect off canvas menu with markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, openlayers-3

I'm working on a mapping project and I need to mark some building to display some data for that specific building. Basically, literally I'm trying to build something like this

[image]

I have found off canvas project and I'm using it for mine map, here is a working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/pg8sdz17/2/) example.
For the map I'm using `openlayers3`, `openstreetmap`, I'm not using `google-maps` and I'm not interesting in using it, I'm just referencing on this picture because they have a nice example of this off canvas display data menu.

As you can see I have marked different area around `NYC` and I would like to, when I click on the example I trigger off canvas menu (don't mind off canvas `nav-bar` style it will change) and display proper data for that object.

Mine question is:
What is the best way to do this, I would like to learn how to glue this off-canvas to mine map, so markers can trigger off-canvas?

I know that there is a hidden `<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />` who I displaying as hamburger icon which is used to trigger off canvas menu. But I do not understand how can I connect all markers to the canvas to display different data for each building.

I would like to learn how can I do this? It will be great to use `javascript` or `jquery` for this, I don't thing that `openlayers3` have this kind of flexibility, but maybe there is, I'm little confused about this, can someone help me build this, thank you.