# Pass object arrays to template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, django-views

I will try rephrase mine [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072156/connect-off-canvas-menu-with-markers) from this post.

I'm using `openlayers3` to display random building markers on the map. You can see it in this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/pg8sdz17/2/) example.

This is the code for the map

```
/* Create the map */
// setting up coordinates for map to display
var city = ol.proj.transform([-73.920935,40.780229], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');


// setting up openlayer3 view
var view = new ol.View({
    center: city,
    zoom: 13
});


// Create the map
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  renderer: 'canvas',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: view
});


// Setup markers
var markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
  tittle: 'City Apratments',
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-73.927870, 40.763633])),
      }),
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-73.917356, 40.763958])),
      }),
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-73.915530, 40.779665])),
      }),
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-73.916045, 40.779372])),
      }),
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-73.919682, 40.777365])),
      }),
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-73.908980, 40.776013])),
      }),
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-73.917356, 40.763958])),
      })
    ]
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixel',
      opacity: 0.75,
      src: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/data/icon.png',
    })
  })
});
map.addLayer(markers);
```

I need to display some data about the building (*street address, picture of building, more info, etc, something like you can see when you interact whit the google map, when you click on the map and you trigger off canvas menu whit some info about that place*), so when you interact and click on the marker template will bi rendered and on it you will see all the data for that object, I need to be able to display different data for different marker building.

QUESTION:

You can see mine `markers` are displayed trough `openlayer3 source.Vector`, how can I pass this `array` of objects to `django-view` then `django-template` from this `javascript` code, how is this possible?

I want to avoid `django-orm` and do this from `js --> django-view --> django-template`.

I goal is to render a template when you click on the `marker`, so you can see some data about the building, furthermore I want to change this template whenever I want.

I would like to understand how can I do this, can someone help, thank you.

Comment: Still not really sure what your question is. Exactly where are you having trouble?

Comment: In linking data to my markers, how to pass markers into django so I can render them in templates.

Comment: You'd do it with Ajax, but I still don't know what bit you are having difficulty with.

Comment: The difficulty is that I don't know how to set it up, I didn't done this before and I want someone explain to me how can I do this, so I can overcome this and learn something out of it

Comment: How to display different data for different markers, and still be able to change the template how I want, you mentioned Ajax, can you please explain to me how?